# UNIX output displayed in one line in mail

Tags: shell, email, unix

My CSV file looks like this:

```
------------------------------
|file count 1       |   10   |
|file count 2       |   10   |
|total file count   | 20     |
------------------------------
```

When I send the same data in mail it is displayed in single line.

```
file count 1 ... 10 file count 2 ... 10 total file count ... 20
```

Thanks.

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: Is it a HTML or pure Text Email?

Comment: I am getting the count form UNIX and storing it into csv file. And while reading the file and sending the data in email it is coming in one line.